# why does not work margin-top on this layout

Tags: css, xhtml, margin

**I want this:**
http://www.img-share.net/uploads/33986layout.png

**But this does not work**
http://jsfiddle.net/RLN8x/1/
please help me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this updated version: http://jsfiddle.net/RLN8x/5/

You need to set the "block" to relative position and use a negative `top` value to push it outside the parent.

Answer (score 1):

You could use relative positioning to do this instead:

```
.block {
    position: relative;
    top: -15px;
    background:#eee;
    margin-left:15px;
    margin-right:15px;
    height:30px; 
}
```